How to correctly invoke java code from dart code?
I need to do more "Mainactivity.java" from the "newcustomAction.dart"
Source dart code:
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

Future newCustomAction() async {
  // Add your function code here!
}

Source java code:
package com.example.project_one;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
}


Please write in full how to change
"Mainactivity.java" and "new custom Action.dart" after adding the java code invocation method.
I do not know how to call java code correctly, I could not find information about this.

FLUTTER CODE
Future<dynamic> callNativeCode() async {
const platformMethodChannel =
  const MethodChannel('your_channel_name');
String _message;
try {
  final String result =
      await platformMethodChannel.invokeMethod('function_name');
  _message = result;
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

}

JAVA CODE
 public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "your_channel_name";
  @Override
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
    .setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
      if (call.method.equals("function_name")) {
        //run java code

         
          result.success("");//return anything you wNt to return here
       
  
      }

    });
}
}

Here you need to set up a platformchannel with any string as your channelName  eg. "your_channel_name". and set a functionName that you want to invoke in the native code eg. "function_name"
